# jquery ui dialog top always > 0

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I'm using the jquery ui dialog for viewing a form.

This form has a large height value, so the top of the dialog is 0px.

I want to change this because there is a menu bar at the top of my window.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the position property

```
$('#some_dialog_selector').dialog({position:['center',10]});
```

this will open the dialog centered horizontally and 10 pixels from the top of the viewport..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you dialog is covering the menubar at the top of the window.
So you want o manually place this dialog lower.

You can use the 'position' option. It can be 'right', 'left', 'bottom' or 'top'
as below -

```
    `$("#register-dialog").dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
            position: 'bottom'
    buttons: {`
```

Or you can position it at "right top". As shown here at the jquery site -

`Specifies where the dialog should be displayed. Possible values: 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom', or an array containing a coordinate pair (in pixel offset from top left of viewport) or the possible string values (e.g. ['right','top'] for top right corner).`